# Using case_when with vector outputs of different length - can I avoid this doubling behaviour?

Tags: r, function, switch-statement

When I use case_when as below, I end up with an unwanted doubling of outputs that were intended to be of length 1 - presumably because case_when matches the length of all possible output vectors.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
decision <- case_when(
  a == b ~ c("A", "B"),
  a > b ~ "A",
  TRUE ~ "B")

result <- decision %>% str_c("+") %>% paste(collapse = " ")
```

The result in this scenario is "B+ B+", when I just want "B+".

When a=b, I get "A+ B+", which is what I want in that scenario.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour, or an alternative function?

Please note that the above is just the simplest parallel I could write. I am using case_when as part of a custom function to define rules applied to numerous input variables to generate a result call.
I had been using multiple if_else statements chained together, but that has significant readability/editing issues and I had been excited to discover case_when and use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

`case_when/ifelse/if_else` all requires arguments to have equal length.  Here, the value returned in some cases have length 2 and some have length 1.  It wouldn't work as mentioned in the `?case_when`

> Both LHS and RHS may have the **same length** of either 1 or n. The value of n must be **consistent across all cases**. The case of n == 0 is treated as a variant of n != 1.

Use `if/else`

```
decision <- if(a == b) c('A', 'B') else if(a > b) 'A' else 'B'
```

-testing

```
library(stringr)
decision %>% 
  str_c("+") %>% 
  str_c(collapse = " ")
[1] "B+"
```

---

If we want to still use `case_when`, wrap it with `list` so that it returns a length of 1 for all cases and then extract the `list` element with `[[`

```
case_when(
  a == b ~ list(c("A", "B")),
  a > b ~ list("A"),
  TRUE ~ list("B"))[[1]]
[1] "B"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail!

Using if/else as you say can work for me, however I have discovered it needs a strict TRUE/FALSE. Some of my inputs had NA values, which I wanted to be handled by the last line of rules (e.g. TRUE ~ "B" in case_when).

I will decide on either cleansing my data of NA values and using if/else, or using case_when wrapped in a list (which isn't so strict on NA. Either should work

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating how you might use `switch` here? Came across if briefly thinking it could be useful but not quite getting it.

Comment: @ChrisP sorry, was thinking a case where you are passing a value instead of a logical expression.  I think the if/else would be better

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the look of case_when for my purposes, and wraping in a list is working nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `case_when` you could also use some `regex`:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

decision <- case_when(
  a == b ~ "A B",
  a > b ~ "A",
  TRUE ~ "B")

stringr::str_replace_all(decision, "([A-B])", "\\1\\+")
```